# Formatting the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Hi I would like to format my bibliography. I want the names to be arranged as follows: Last name (A), First name (A), Last name (B), First name (B). But for me it looks like this:
[image]

My code is

```
\usepackage[
  sorting=nty,
  citestyle=authoryear,
      backend=biber,
     bibstyle=authoryear,
   autolang=hyphen,
  maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragment into a complete compilable document that shows the problem, i.e. a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Your code doesn't lead to abbreviated first names for me.

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` as suggested in Alan's link should do what you want. If it does not, you need to show us a compilable example document that reproduces your status quo (and not just a few code snippets).

Comment: `citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to the shorter and arguably clearer `style=authoryear,`. `sorting=nty,` sorts by name-title-year and is a debatable choice for an otherwise author-year citation/bibliography setup (a work called "A" published in 2022 will be sorted before "B" published in 2020 - but your readers only know author and year from the citation labels, not the title). `nameyeardelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter and would better be redefined with that interface: `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`